# Ordering a GROUP_CONCAT Column (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I was wondering if there was a way to order a GROUP_CONCAT-ed column by another column. Here's my example:

***Tables***

users

```
 id | name
----+------------
  0 | John Smith
```

users_majors

```
user_id | major_id | order
--------+----------+-------
   0    |    2     |  1
   0    |    1     |  0
```

majors

```
 id | name
----+-------------
  0 | Biology
  1 | Chemistry
  2 | Engineering
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT `users`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `majors`.name) AS major, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `users_majors`.order) AS major_order
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN users_majors ON (users_majors.user_id = users.id)
LEFT JOIN majors ON (majors.id = users_majors.major_id)
GROUP BY users.id
```

I receive this result set, as expected:

```
id | name        | major                 | major_order
---+-------------+-----------------------+-------------
 0 | John Smith  | Engineering,Chemistry | 1,0
```

What I want to do is have the "major" column automatically be sorted by the "major_order" column, so I can remove that column and have the result set look like this:

```
id | name        | major
---+-------------+-----------------------
 0 | John Smith  | Chemistry,Engineering
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) includes an ORDER BY option.

```
SELECT `users`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `majors`.name ORDER BY `users_majors`.order) AS major, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `users_majors`.order) AS major_order
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN users_majors ON (users_majors.user_id = users.id)
LEFT JOIN majors ON (majors.id = users_majors.major_id)
GROUP BY users.id
```